# Getting all public statuses with a FQL query?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have been trawling around the Facebook API documentation looking for something and haven't found what I want...so I thought I could ask here to confirm my suspicions and dash all my hopes.

Essentially what I am wanting to achieve is get a list of ALL (from any user) public statuses that contain a particular set of query terms.

So say I have a list of terms: cat, dog, mouse, elephant.

I would like to get ALL public statuses that contain EITHER cat OR dog OR mouse OR elephant.

Is this possible?

I really do appreciate any feedback on this; I've been trying for days to figure this out and it just will not work.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated...